# Enable JMX port for monitoring kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

Using reference to https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/MP_for_Apache_Kafka:1.10/Kafka/Kafka_JMX,
I created the jmx_local.config and modified the Kafka start up script)

The Kafka start up script picks the jmx_local.coonfig but the port is not getting exposed.
This is what I see on grepping the java process:

```
"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/usr/local/etc/kafka/jmx_local.conf kafka.Kafka /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties"

cat /usr/local/etc/kafka/jmx_local.conf
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9395
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Also tried with port 10167 but the port is not enabled. Also modified as 'com.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9395'
I could see the other jmx properties.

Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

I did grep -rl "jmxremote" /usr/local/Cellar/kafka/2.6.0, and found the jxm config was considered from bin/kafka-run-class.sh. So added 'Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9395' in bin/kafka-run-class.sh and restarted the kafka service.

To find if the port is available:
netstat -an | grep 1099